# EmberJS re-use same template, but displays the template twice

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am playing with Ember, and building a basic contact management app to learn Ember. I am following the Emberjs getting started guide. Only instead of doing a "to-do" app, Im doing my own thing in hopes of picking it up better.

My Router, and Routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', function() {
        this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' });
        this.route('motoDigitalTrue');
    });

    this.resource('about');
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.User.find(); 
    }
});

App.UsersMotoDigitalTrueRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.User.filter(function(user) {
            if (user.get('motoDigital')) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    },

    renderTemplate: function(controller) {
        this.render('users', {
            controller:controller
        });
    }
});
```

Essentially, I have a template named 'users' that I want to reuse. This template lists all the users. I have a sorting button that when clicked, will only display the users who have the `motoDigitalTrue` property set to `true`. The sorting is correct, but it just displays another `Users` template, rather than re-populating the original.

My Users template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="users"> 
  <div class="span10 tableContainer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary createUser" {{action createUser}}><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add a Contact</button>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Sort<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {{#linkTo 'users.motoDigitalTrue' activeClass="selected"}}Receiving MOTO Digital{{/linkTo}}
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tableScrollable">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="nameHead">Name</th>
          <th class="companyHead">Company</th>
          <th class="emailHead">Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td class="name">&nbsp</td>
          <td class="company">&nbsp</td>
          <td class="email">&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
      {{#each model}}

        <tr>
          <td class="name"><i class="icon-user"></i> <strong>{{#linkTo 'user' this }}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}{{/linkTo}}</strong></td>
          <td class="company">{{company}}</td>
          <td class="email"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> <a {{bindAttr mailto="email"}}>{{email}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    {{#if isCreateUser}}
         <div class="well">
                {{partial 'users/createUser'}}
                <button {{action 'saveUser'}} class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        {{outlet}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
  </script>
```

I have been unable to find an answer, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your case to reuse templates, you should try using a `partial`, have a look [here.](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/)

For example, rename your `users` template to `_users`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='_users'>
  ...
</script>
```

and then use the `partial` helper to render it

```
{{partial users}}
```

Note that `{{partial}}` takes the template to be rendered as an argument, and renders that template in place. This means that it does not change context or scope. It simply renders the given template with the current scope.

Hope it helps.